# laravel publish site issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, routes

I need to publish my web app written in laravel 4,
i've followed many tutorial in internet but i'm not able to make it works correctly.

i'm on a dedicate server with centos 6.6 where resides another website so the laravel app should be placed in a sub folder named `vols`

this is the current folder structure:

```
/
  var/
    www/
       laravel/
          app/
          bootstrap/
          vendor/
          ...
       html/
          vols/
          other files of my website
```

i've changed the paths inside `bootstrap/paths.php` to

```
'app' => __DIR__.'/../../laravel/app'
'public' => __DIR__.'/../../html/vols'
'base' => __DIR__.'/../../laravel'
'storage' => __DIR__.'/../../laravel/app/storage'
```

and the paths inside `vols/index.php` to

```
require __DIR__.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/start.php';
```

my first controller is named `volunteers`, so if visit `http://mydomain/vols` i should be redirected to `http://mydomain/vols/volunteers`
instead i see this error message: `The requested URL /vols/volunteers was not found on this server.`

if i try to connect to `http://mydomain/vols/index.php/volunteers` everything works correctly but i don't want index.php in my route.

i think i should work on `.htaccess` inside `vols` folder, but i've never studied how it really works, so i'm just copying some random snippets from internet substituting `public` with `vols`.

currently it look like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^vols
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ vols/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Some solutions suggests to create vhost, technically i can do that, but i don't know how.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should place the following .htaccess in your vols folder -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /vols/

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: this seems to be the default one, which is not working, i don't know why!

Comment: what error do you get? also are you sure that mod_rewrite is enabled?

Comment: it's a 404: The requested URL /vols/volunteers was not found on this server. from php info, mod_rewrite, is between the loaded modules

Comment: Add `RewriteBase /vols/` under `RewriteEngine On` [could also re-copy the code above]